# How to correctly style drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I ran into problems while styling drop-down menu. Everything is working fine but I have absolute positioning in my CSS (which works) but it of course doesn't work properly when I change my screen resolution. I am more programmer than a designer.

Here is my menu:

```
<div class="navigation">
<!-- some links -->
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="gallery.html">Galerie</a>
        <div id="submenu">
            <a href="galleryOldRooms.html" title="Starší pokoje">Starší pokoje</a><br />
            <a href="galleryNewRooms.html" title="Novější pokoje">Novější pokoje</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS

```
#submenu {
   display: none;
   padding: 0px;
   margin-top: 5em;
   margin-left: 27.5em;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
}
.nav a {
   border-right: 2px solid #161616;
   color: #CCC;
   float: left;
   font: bold 1em Verdana,sans-serif;
   line-height: 51px;
   padding: 0 20px;
}
```

And piece of jQuery which does the drop out

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").hover(function() {
        $("#submenu").fadeIn(); 
        }, 
    function() {
        $("#submenu").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

How can I improve this to be it more browser and resolution independent?

### Edit

When I increase or decrease resolution of my display or try to look at it on bigger screen, the the drop-down menu is moved to either left or right side depending on the resolution.  Which is obviously something I don't. [Here](http://www.stavarov-ubytovna.cz) is the link, it's not finished.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening when you re-size and what behavior you are looking for?  Do you have a link to the site with the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here. I've modified the layout to be more inline with the way most developers set up this type of menu. I've also reversed most of your IDs and classes, which are being used in such a way as to almost guarantee duplicate IDs.

This may not be an ideal answer to your question, but I think there's some helpful information in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrPse/8/

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
}
#nav a {
    border-right: 2px solid #161616;
    color: #CCC;
    float: left;
    font: bold 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 51px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
#nav > li {position: relative; display: inline-block;}
#nav li ul li a {border-right: 0;}
.submenu {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    width: 180px;
}
.submenu li a {border-right: 0;}

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Úvod</a></li>
    <li><a href="prices.html">Ceník</a></li>
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="gallery.html">Galerie</a>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a title="Starší pokoje" href="galleryOldRooms.html">Starší pokoje</a></li>
            <li><a title="Novější pokoje" href="galleryNewRooms.html">Novější pokoje</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>

    </li>
</ul>

$(".menu").hover(function () {
    $(this).children(".submenu").fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).children(".submenu").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `#menu` must have a `position:relative;`

This way, the `#submenu` will have `position:absolute;` according to the `#menu` and inside of it, `left:0px;` means it will stick on the left border of the `#menu` and this is what you want, no need for a `margin-left` and a `margin-top`, just add `top:30px;` and test it if its positioned correctly under **Galerie**, maybe you'll need to increase the top or decrease it.

```
#menu
{
    position:relative;
}
#submenu {
   display: none;
   padding: 0px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top:30px; //find the best value
}
```

**UPDATE**

When I said that the `#menu` must have a `position:relative;` I thought that the `#menu` is a div that only contains the `<a>` **Galerie**, if this is not the case, if the `#menu` contains all the 4 links: Uvod .. Cenik.. etc... then of course it will stick at the beginning.

What you need to do is to add a **special div container** for the Galerie, means...

```
<div id="menu">
   <a href="">Uvod</a>
   <a href="">Cenik</a>
   <div id="galerieParent">
       <a href="">Galerie</a>
       <div id="submenu">
          ......
       </div>
   </div>
   <a href="">Kontakt</a>
</div>
```

Now, the `position:relative;` must be set for `#galerieParent`.

Comment: I've done it exactly as you wrote but the menu is sticked to the beginning of the menu, not to the Galerie, so where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some CSS

```
#menu {position:relative;}
```

and change

```
#submenu {margin-left:14.5em;}
```

adjust as needed.